# Interface issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

i added a property 'WrmVersion' in interface IResourcePolicy but i am not getting those thing in the implementation side means here it should come in the List
view data. means SubItems.Add(((IResourcePolicy)Data).WrmVersion is not getting

This is the interface

```
public interface IResourcePolicy
   {
          DataVersion WrmVersion
       {
           get;
           set;
       }
          bool ResourcePolicyEnabled
      {
         get;
         set;
      }

  }
```

*i am implementing it in*

```
   public new IResourcePolicy Data
         {
            get
            {
               return (IResourcePolicy)base.Data;
            }
         }


  protected override void OnUpdate()
         {


if(Data != null)
               {
                  Text = base.Data.Name;
                  if(SubItems.Count == 1)
                  {
                     SubItems.Add(((IResourcePolicy)Data).ResourcePolicyEnabled.ToString());

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that 'true' or 'false' (depending on your expected value) is not being added to the ListView when OnUpdate is fired? Is Data not null and is there exactly one item in ListView.Items at that time? What happens when you add a breakpoint and step through it?

Comment: no ineed to get version value

Comment: Is there any DLL issue probs will exist

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is i am referencing Old DLL ,,what actually happened is i created test application added only relevant forms to test application.So i need to copy the Dll from test application to Original side